# Lifting state up and accessing values of a dynamically created input text field

Tags: reactjs

In my Component, I am opening up a Modal and passing a form like this:-

```
<Modal
  show={showGroupModal}
  onCancel={closeGroupModalHandler}
  header="Please add Group Name"
  contentClass="player-admin__modal-content"
>
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={addGroupSubmitHandler}>
      <NonFormikInput
        type="text"
        placeholder={formatValue ? "Enter Group Name" : "Enter Team Name"}
        nogat={nogat}
        getTextValue={getTextValueHandler}
      />
      <Button type="submit" text="Submit"></Button>
      <Button type="button" text="Cancel" onClick={closeGroupModalHandler}>
        {" "}
      </Button>
    </form>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

The value {nogat} is a variable value being fetched from a MONGODB collection. This value is passed to a child component, where I am using .map() to create number of input boxes based on number passed via nogat, like this:-

```
const NonFormikInput = (props) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setTitle(event.target.value)
        props.getTextValue(title)
    }
    const newValues = [...Array(props.nogat)].map((_,i) => i + 1)
    const newValues1 = newValues.map(number => {
        return (
            <input
            key={number}
            id={number}
            className="non-formikinput__text"    
             type={props.type} 
             placeholder={props.placeholder}
             onChange={changeHandler}
             value={title}
             />        
        )
    })
    return (
        newValues1
    )   
}
```

The onChange function in this component should ideally lift the state up via this statement
props.getTextValue(title)
It is doing this correctly and I can see the value in my parent component also correctly.

My Problem:- In the child component the input text field is wired in such a way that whatever I type on any one input field is getting reflected in all the subsequent text boxes.

I figured that this is probably because I wired the value prop as a state field title and this is now getting spread across all the input fields coming from the .map function.

Is there a way to segregate the input values so that I am uniquely able to capture values from every field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of storing a string in the state variable store an object that can have the title of each input with key as its number. Pass the number to the changeHandler along with the event to set the titles. Now in the parent element, you can access the text of any input by its number.

```
const NonFormikInput = (props) => {
    const [titles, setTitles] = useState({})
    const changeHandler = (event, number) => {
        setTitles({...titles, [number]: event.target.value});
        props.getTextValue(titles)
    }
    const newValues = [...Array(props.nogat)].map((_,i) => i + 1)
    const newValues1 = newValues.map(number => {
        return (
            <input
            key={number}
            id={number}
            className="non-formikinput__text"    
            type={props.type} 
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            onChange={(event) => changeHandler(event, number)}
            value={number in titles ? titles[number] : ""}
            />        
        )
    })
    return (
        newValues1
    )   
}
```